# How can I set starting directory for D: in WSL2?

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using Ubuntu-20.04 WSL2 in Windows 10.

I want to approach `D:` when I open my terminal, so I added this in my workspace `settings.json`:

```json
"source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
"colorScheme": "Monokai Night",
"startingDirectory": "\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-20.04\\mnt\\d" //added this
```

But it is not working (this code connected me to default of `mnt/c/Users/username`).

So I also tried this:

```json
"source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl",
"colorScheme": "Monokai Night",
"startingDirectory": "\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-20.04\\mnt" //added this
```

It is working.

How can I set starting directory for `d`?

Comment: This worked for me in WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS `"\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu-22.04\\home\\watashi"`

Answer (score 2):

For mounted directories like `D:`, setting the mount point like `/mnt/d` won't work (h/t [@Dominique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279155/dominique)).

- Either use a Windows-style path (with backslashes escaped):

  ```json
  "startingDirectory": "D:\\"
  ```
- Or use Linux-style slashes in newer versions (slashes do **not** need to be escaped):

  ```json
  "startingDirectory": "D:/"
  ```

  <sup>*– Requires [Windows Terminal 1.11.2421.0](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.11.2421.0) on Windows 10 21H2 or Windows 11*</sup>

---

Alternatively, ignore the Windows Terminal settings and just `cd` at the end of your `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
cd /mnt/d
```

Comment: In order to use a mounting point, don't you need to create it first?

Comment: @Dominique Do you mean `/mnt/c/Foo/Bar`? Another user just added that example an hour ago. I'm not sure it works either -- testing now.

Comment: @Dominique Confirmed, `/mnt/c/Foo/Bar` doesn't work on my end. Removed, thanks.

Comment: @tdy Did you try it with a real path?  I was just modifying your example.  If `C:\Foo\Bar` exists on the drive, then (a) `/mnt/c/Foo/Bar` will also exist and (b) `//wsl$/<distroName>/mnt/c/Foo/Bar` would be a valid startingDirectory.

Comment: @Dominique No, you don't need to create it, because `/mnt/c` is automatically created by WSL.  Try it with a "real" example such as `//wsl$/<distroname>/mnt/c/Windows/System32` for instance.  It should work.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Actually after more testing, even `//wsl$/<distro>/mnt/c` alone does not work. Using C:\ (in settings) or C:\\ (in json) works, but not via mount point. I'll revise again.

Comment: @tdy Actually that does make sense since the `/mnt/c` mount isn't available until *after* WSL starts.  And anyway, `C:\` is so much easier than `//wsl$/<distro>/mnt/c` anyway ;-)